# Different session Id from the same IP on the same time

Tags: c#, session

In my application every time a user lands on my website I check that user with it's session ID and make a insert(with all the details ip,browser etc) into the database **if its a different session ID**.

```
string sessionId = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
if (objDB.checkDuplicate("session", "sessionId", sessionId))
{
    // code to make insert in database
}
```

But when checking database I am getting **multiple inserts from same IP at the same time.**

Can anybody explain why this happens?

**NOTE :** SESSION of the user is different so `checkDuplicate()` works fine but how can a user have a different session ID at the same time? (or such a sort span of time)

Comment: Could be that they are not accepting cookies and each time they access a page it is a new session? Or something similar caused by their firewall.

Comment: @aserwin: if so what to do user uniqueness over a session(period of time)

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic : so you mean to say that those insert are form different user from same IP at same time

Comment: yes, along the lines of Oscar's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably it's multiple people sharing the same connection over a router or proxy server.

Comment: Or multiple browser tabs/windows from one user, depending on the browser (yes it differs, I once checked empirically)

Comment: no not possible because I am getting multipal insert for almost every 3rd user and i don't think that much user are using my website behind the router

Comment: if it differs for every tab ... what would you suggest to do check user uniqueness over a session

Comment: +1. This is most likely reason for seam id at the same time. @Champ, do you know how IP routing works? Have you seen IP of machines at your home (I bet it's 192.168.0.x)...

Comment: Or instead of router there is forward proxy

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov : yes I know what what IP is and What's my machine IP is .But the point is when  I check no of user online with google analytics It 5-10 user at a time and Iam having insert in the db almost every second. that horable

Comment: @Champ, see more random reasons in my answer. Side note - tracking users with session ID cookie is unreliable, use custom one that you control (maybe even persistent one - be aware that you may need to notify users about it, you know if care about legal stuff)...

Answer (score 2):

More reasons (being behind router/proxy is most likely one) to have different session Id for same IP

- restarting browser will make new session Id for the same user (as long it is set in session cookies)
- opening separate browsing session (i.e. normal vs. private for IE, depending on configuration and browser tabs may be treated as separate sessions)
- different users on the same computer

Another set of reasons for different session Id is based on failure to set persist session cookie between requests:

- I think if there is no writes to ASP.Net session state cookie can be regenerated on every request (need to verify)
- cookie could be disabled (rare, but possible)
- cookie can be blocked (i.e. lack of P3P policy for pages/images in IFrame) or some other policy in browser

There are valid reasons to get multiple browser windows for the same sessionId for the same user (tabs in same "browser session", "open in new window/tab" with Ctrl+click ). You as site creator have to decide if you want to try to enforce "single session = single window" policy or deal with potentially multiple windows opened in the same session. There is no reasonable way I know to detect case when same session Id is used in different tabs, especially if you have to support GET requests (otherwise you can dump some addition ID into hidden field).